# Kafka and zookeeper dependancies

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

My company is about to introduce kafka. However, i was not able to conprehend why either zookeeper or kafka confinguration, does not require to specify one or another existence.

For example, i neither find definition of kafka ip in zookeeper nor in kakfa definition of zookeeper ip in their config.

Can someone explain ?

Comment: Zookeeper doesn't depend on Kafka at all. That would be circular dependency and make it hard to install Kafka...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for kafka server you should have server.properties file. It contains property `zookeeper.connect`

official documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs